# How to add more than one skill to an assistant in IBM Watson Assistant?

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-watson, watson-conversation

I have created few skills under IBM Watson Assistant and also created one assistant to link the one skill. I would like to know how to add more than one skills to a single assistant ?

Answer (score 2):

Based on the [documentation for IBM Watson Assistant on creating asisstants](https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/assistant/create-assistant.html#creating-assistants) you can only have one skill per assistant at this time.

I tested adding more by going into the tool for editing a skill, then clicked on the **Deploy** option in the menu, selected an existing assistant and got to the overview. Right now only one skill is accepted.